# Internal error occurred in Eclipse Juno during Maven Project Import/Update

Tags: svn, maven, eclipse-juno, m2e, m2e-wtp

I am using **Eclipse Juno** (tried SR1 & SR2) with the **m2e WTP plugin** installed. (I have also tried the same with just the m2e plugin) and I get the following:

> An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
>   org/eclipse/m2e/wtp/WTPProjectsUtil

This happens when I try to import a project and also when I try to run the mvn update. Below is the image of the error:

[image: Error popup]

Also, for some reason the update or import switches the project run time setting. I have configured it to **WAS 8.5 with Java 7** but it switches **back to 1.5 compilation level** even though in my Eclipse preference from SVN it says Java 1.7. Any help will be really appreciated.

**Update** Below is the POM file for the Web project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>myprojectWAR</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- dependencies here! -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>myprojectWAR</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/myprojectWAR</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor />
                    <manifestSections>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <name>JAX-WS engine</name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>true</DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                    </manifestSections>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you please provide the pom file here ? more specifically i want to see the contents of `<resources>` in your pom.xml.

Comment: I have added the pom file for the WAR app.

Comment: It could help if you provide the stacktrace of this event. See the "Error Log" view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after installing "WebSphere® Application Server V8.5 Tools for Juno". Updating to the latest "m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP" in the eclipse marketplace solved the problem. I'm not sure if this was your problem but might help other people facing this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64 bits version of eclipse? I had the same problem until I switched back to 32 bits. I have no explanation.